# How to measure CPU Steal Time with Prometheus Node-exporter metrics

Tags: prometheus, cpu, prometheus-node-exporter

How CPU Steal Time can be measured by Prometheus Node-exporter CPU metrics?

We have an OpenStack/KVM environment and we want to measure/Know how much CPU steal happens (Percent) in our Computes/Hosts/Hypervisors.

Comment: Is `node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="steal"}` what you are looking for?

Comment: And regarding "if CPU steal happens" - yes it happens. Only real question is how much does it happen.

Comment: @markalex Tnx,  we want to know "if CPU steal happens?" and "How much does it happen"

Answer (score 2):

Node exporter exposes metric `node_cpu_seconds_total` with `mode` **steal** for counter of CPU time being stolen.

This metric is exposed by default as part of `cpu` collector.

Expression like

```
sum by (instance, cpu) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="steal"} [2m]))
```

can show you how much (in percents) CPU steal happened on every CPU of every machine.